# I tried to wrench myself free from his grip

Tags: meaning-in-context

I looked the meaning for wrench. There are so many meaning for the same word based on the context. Also I found below sentence in the dictionary. What does this sentence means? I'm not getting it. Does it mean - He was holding the girl tightly with both hand and she pushed his hands away forcefully to escape?

I mean whether the man was holing the woman like in this [image](http://www.123rf.com/photo_13763085_attractive-young-couple-in-loving-embrace-with-the-man-hugging-the-woman-tightly-from-behind.html) but forcefully and tightly and she pushed his hands away forcefully to escape?

> [I tried to wrench myself free from his grip](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/wrench).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It means that **she tried to violently twist herself free from his grip**. The verb is transitive in this sentence: *myself* is the direct object, so the first two definitions apply here.

She probably twisted her entire body in all directions rather than merely pushing his hands away forcefully. When one uses a wrench, one **twists** whatever the wrench is gripping; one doesn't push it.